# How to create a parser in erlang

Tags: erlang, parser-generator

How to create a parser in erlang that will take in a properly formed propositional formula and converts it into some internal representation.

Listing the available tools for creating a parser in erlang and also projects that uses them can be helpful.

Comment: To answer your question need to know the more details.

Comment: Look up the documentation for [leex](http://erlang.org/doc/man/leex.html) and [yecc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/yecc.html).

Comment: Here's how to build your own parser for expressions, without any use of parser generator tools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769

Answer (score 8):

You can use `leex`, `yecc`, `spell1` and some others.

- [leex](http://erlang.org/doc/man/leex.html): A regular expression based lexical analyzer generator for Erlang, similar to lex or flex. A lexer file includes parts for `Definition`, `Rules` and also Erlang codes.
- [yecc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/yecc.html): An LALR-1 parser generator for Erlang, similar to yacc. A parser generator file includes parts for `Non-terminals`, `Terminals`, `Rules` and `Root-symbols`.
- [spell1](https://github.com/rvirding/spell1): An LL(1) parser generator for Erlang and [LFE](http://lfe.io/) which is a Lisp dialect language on top of Erlang.
- [neotoma](https://github.com/seancribbs/neotoma): A packrat parser-generator for Erlang for Parsing Expression Grammars (PEGs).

---

Some open source projects that uses them:

- [Efene](https://github.com/efene/efene): Alternative syntax for the Erlang Programming Language focusing on simplicity, ease of use. It uses leex and yecc for parsing the language syntax of Efene.
- [ErlyDTL](https://github.com/erlydtl/erlydtl): Django templates for Erlang which uses leex and yecc to parse Django based template language.
- [Tnesia](https://github.com/bisphone/Tnesia): A time-series database which has a SQL-like language (TQL) which implemented with leex and yecc.

This [Slide](http://www.slideshare.net/hamidreza-s/create-your-own-language) includes some useful examples about how to use them.